How to create a .docx file with an ActiveX control that shows the activation prompt in all Office versions?
I am an engineer working in the security team of an IT company. To prevent email phishing attacks against employees, I am trying to create a test phishing email. I plan to attach a .docx file containing an ActiveX control, and consider someone phished if they click the button to activate the ActiveX.
To identify who was phished, I want to set up a simple web server on the internal network and insert a WebBrowser ActiveX control in the document that connects to the web server when activated, so I can log the accesses.
I created the .docx file using Office 2010, but in Office 2013 and later versions, the activation button does not appear. Actual malicious files show this button regardless of version. How can I create a file that shows the activation button in all Office versions?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ax:ocx ax:classid="{8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2}" ax:persistence="persistPropertyBag"
  xmlns:ax="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/activeX"
  xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
  <ax:ocxPr ax:name="ExtentX" ax:value="15901"/>
  <ax:ocxPr ax:name="ExtentY" ax:value="7952"/>
  <ax:ocxPr ax:name="ViewMode" ax:value="0"/>
  <ax:ocxPr ax:name="Offline" ax:value="0"/>
  <ax:ocxPr ax:name="Silent" ax:value="0"/>
  <ax:ocxPr ax:name="RegisterAsBrowser" ax:value="0"/>
  <ax:ocxPr ax:name="RegisterAsDropTarget" ax:value="1"/>
  <ax:ocxPr ax:name="AutoArrange" ax:value="0"/>
  <ax:ocxPr ax:name="NoClientEdge" ax:value="0"/>
  <ax:ocxPr ax:name="AlignLeft" ax:value="0"/>
  <ax:ocxPr ax:name="NoWebView" ax:value="0"/>
  <ax:ocxPr ax:name="HideFileNames" ax:value="0"/>
  <ax:ocxPr ax:name="SingleClick" ax:value="0"/>
  <ax:ocxPr ax:name="SingleSelection" ax:value="0"/>
  <ax:ocxPr ax:name="NoFolders" ax:value="0"/>
  <ax:ocxPr ax:name="Transparent" ax:value="0"/>
  <ax:ocxPr ax:name="ViewID" ax:value="{0057D0E0-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262}"/>
  <ax:ocxPr ax:name="Location" ax:value="http://you_are_infected.com"/>
</ax:ocx>

this is activex1.xml

I was expecting the ActiveX activation button to appear consistently across all Office versions when opening this .docx file, just like it does with actual malicious files containing ActiveX exploits. Since the goal is to simulate a realistic phishing attack for employee training, I need the file to trigger the ActiveX activation prompt in all Office versions that my employees are using.

TBH, I think a lot of people probably have Word set up so it disables ActiveX controls now. I just wonder whether the sort of attack you are seeing either uses a [ MACROBUTTON } field which fires a VBA routine when clicked, and/or whether that would also be a viable way to perform your tests.

The malware I'm trying to mimic uses the webbrowser ActiveX control and simply accesses a specified URL when the user clicks the activate button.

I think the user will notice if I use a macrobutton, and I want to use a method that the user won't notice.

It's not really my area, but do the malicious files you've seen definitely use an ActiveX control, and specifically an ActiveX web browser control? Because there are permissions/security differences, I.e. a FORMS2 control might get through with security settings that would disallow a web browser control. Macrobutton displaying an image not enough? Your choice of course!
